# AlisaMatch regex

Tags: regex, apache2, mod-alias

I am trying to map a URL based on the filename it has to a fileshare directory. 
Here is the URL that i am using 
http://x.x.x.x/606547/abc.xyz.aaa/MOVIE/some.video.file-xxxxxxxx.nff?c=564378
(Where .nff is file extension).

And here is the ALiasMatch settings i have configured in default sites config file. 
The apache2 is running on ubuntu.

```
AliasMatch ^/[.?]/(*.nff)$ /srv/samba/Assets/$1
    <Directory "/srv/samba/Assets">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        #Order deny,allow
        #Deny from all
        #Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
```

I am getting forbidden error when i runt hat URL in browser. I file directory/file  permissions are correct. 
Can you anyone please suggest is this problem with regex or problem with configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is incorrect, using a preceding `*` before the dot `.` will not be recognized.

Try using the following:

```
AliasMatch /([^/]*\.nff).*$ /srv/samba/Assets/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this regex instead:

```
AliasMatch /([^./]+\.nff)$ /srv/samba/Assets/$1
```